# PHP Oauth::fetch to work with proxy

Tags: php, oauth, proxy

I am accessing an OAUTH protected resource using the [FETCH method of the OAUTH class](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php) in PHP like below

```
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);//Show all errors
        $ACCESS_TOKEN = "{MyAccessToken}";
        $ACCESS_SECRET = "{MyAccessTokenSecret}";
        $CONSUMER_KEY = "{MyConsumerKey}";
        $CONSUMER_SECRET = "{MyConsumerKeySecret}";
        $url = "https://company.desk.com/api/v2/customers/search?phone=123456";     
        $oauth = new OAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET);
        $oauth->setToken($ACCESS_TOKEN, $ACCESS_SECRET);
        $oauth->disableSSLChecks();
        $oauth->fetch($url);
        echo $oauth->getLastResponse();
?>
```

This is actually a request to the DESK.COM Rest API, this seems to work just fine when a normal GET request is made to my PHP script file, a twist just appeared when we were asked to access this resource ($url) via a proxy, since our hosting platform only allows us to access any http resource via a predefined proxy. By reading the documentation available for PHP OAuth class I found that there is no method available to make it work with proxy url.

I need recommendations about how i can get this working via proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a new API with that proxy as its domain URL? Or modify the existing one?